# How to tell object type from NSPersistentHistoryChange

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to use **Persistent History Tracking** to implement data synchronization with the server. The idea is that for every NSPersistentHistoryTransaction, I want to (eventually) make analogous REST requests to perform identical change on the server.

My code iterates through all the changes in the transaction. When the change is a DELETE, I can't figure out, how to tell what object type was deleted. As far as I can tell, the only thing I've got is the tombstone - which are some of the original object's fields (externalId in my case). While ID is an identifier, I also need to know what entity that ID belongs to.

The documentation for the whole Core Data feature is next to none :-/

Is this even a good use case for Persistent History Tracking?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have asked the same question on Apple Developer forum:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116951

Long story short: **change.changedObjectID.entity.name** is what I needed.